# Java : An item was lost after passing the same listArray to the next Function

Tags: java, arraylist, parameter-passing

There's a problem in the passing of the `listArray` to the function after I passed the same `listArray` to the next function. The item at the first index was missing.

I've tried to find the problem within the functions to see if whether it was in the function. But after test checking the passed Collection, the problem was in the argument passing.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Process> listArray = new ArrayList<Process>(); // The `Process` here is user defined datatype

    ***some loop code to get an input from the user...

    Chart(listArray);
    List<Process> fcfsListArray = new ArrayList<Process>(fcfsScheduling(listArray));
        for(Process k : listArray){
            System.out.println(k.getProcessName()); // TEST CHECK fcfs
        } 
        List<Process> sjfNpListArray = new ArrayList<Process>(sjfNpScheduling(listArray));
        for(Process k : listArray){
            System.out.println(k.getProcessName()); // TEST CHECK sjfNp
        }
        //some functions...
}

public static List<Process> fcfsScheduling(List<Process> listArray){

    int n = listArray.size();
    int timeFrame = startingTimeFrame(listArray);
    int processCompleted = 0;

    while(processCompleted != n){
        for(int index = 0  ; index < n ; index ++){
            Process currentProcessor  = listArray.get(index);

            boolean isFinished = currentProcessor.getisCompleted();
            if(isFinished != true){
                int currentArrival = currentProcessor.getProcessArrival();
                if(currentArrival <=timeFrame){
                    currentProcessor.setProcessStart(timeFrame);
                    timeFrame+=currentProcessor.getProcessBurst();          // Sets the time frame where the current process will end.
                    currentProcessor.setProcessEnd(timeFrame);
                    currentProcessor.setisCompleted(true);
                    computeWaitingTime(currentProcessor);                   // compute for the waiting time of the processor;
                    listArray.set(index, currentProcessor);
                    processCompleted += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return listArray;

}
public static List<Process> sjfNpScheduling(List<Process> listArray){
        int n  = listArray.size();
        int processCompleted = 0;
        int timeFrame = startingTimeFrame(listArray);

        // Loop until all processors are completely finished
        while(processCompleted != n){

            Process toProcess  = new Process();
            int processIndex = 0;
            int leastBurstTime = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

           // Find for the PROCESS with the least ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME 
           for(int i = 0 ; i < listArray.size(); i++){
                Process currentProcess = listArray.get(i);
                int processBurst = currentProcess.getProcessBurst();
                int processArrival = currentProcess.getProcessArrival();
                boolean isCompleted = currentProcess.getisCompleted();
                if(isCompleted != true){
                    if(processBurst < leastBurstTime && processArrival <= timeFrame){
                        toProcess = currentProcess;
                        leastBurstTime = processBurst;
                        processIndex = i;
                    }
                }   
           }
           int processBurstTime = toProcess.getProcessBurst();

           toProcess.setProcessStart(timeFrame);
           timeFrame+=processBurstTime;
           toProcess.setProcessEnd(timeFrame);
           toProcess.setisCompleted(true);
           computeWaitingTime(toProcess);
           listArray.set(processIndex, toProcess);
           processCompleted += 1;

        }
        return listArray;
    }
public static int startingTimeFrame(List<Process> listArray){
        int n = listArray.size();
        int leastTime = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
            int arrivalTime  = listArray.get(x).getProcessArrival();    
            if(arrivalTime < leastTime) leastTime = arrivalTime;
        }
        return leastTime;
    }
public static void Chart(List<Process> listArray){
           System.out.println("=================================================");
           System.out.println("|++++++++++++++++ PROCESS CHART ++++++++++++++++|");
           System.out.println("=================================================");
           System.out.println();

           int n = listArray.size();
           int matSizeRow = n + 1;
           String[][] matChart = new String[matSizeRow][3];
            matChart[0][0] = "\t Process";
            matChart[0][1] = "\t Burst";
            matChart[0][2] = "\t Arrival \t";

           for(int x = 0; x < n;x++){
               Process currentProcess = listArray.get(x);
               int index = x+1;
               matChart[index][0] = "\t "+currentProcess.getProcessName();
               matChart[index][1] = "\t\t "+Integer.toString(currentProcess.getProcessBurst());
               matChart[index][2] = "\t\t "+Integer.toString(currentProcess.getProcessArrival()) +" \t";

            }
           for(String[] row :matChart){
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
               System.out.println();
           }
       }
//USER DEFINED DATATYPE : PROCESS

public class Process{
    private String processName;
    private  int processBurst;
    private int processArrival;
    private int processPriority;
    private int processStart;
    private int processEnd;
    private double waitingTime = 0;
    private boolean isCompleted = false;


public void setProcessPriority(int n){
    this.processPriority = n;
}
public int getProcessPriority(){
    return this.processPriority;
}
public void setisCompleted(boolean condition){
    this.isCompleted = condition;
}
public boolean getisCompleted(){
    return this.isCompleted;
}
public void setWaitingTime(double objStart){
    this.waitingTime = objStart;
}
public double getWaitingTime(){
    return this.waitingTime;
}
public void setProcessStart(int objStart){
    this.processStart = objStart;
}
public int getProcessStart(){
    return this.processStart;
}
public void setProcessEnd(int n){
    this.processEnd = n;
}
public int getProcessEnd(){
    return this.processEnd;
}
public void setProcessName(String objName){
    this.processName = objName;
}
public String getProcessName(){
    return this.processName;
}
public void setProcessBurst(int objBurst){
    this.processBurst = objBurst;
}
public int getProcessBurst(){
    return this.processBurst;
}
public void setProcessArrival(int objArrival) {
    this.processArrival= objArrival;
} 
public int getProcessArrival(){
    return this.processArrival;
}
}
```

Suppose I input a 3 Process variable in `listArray`,  each has a name `p1,p2,p3`

On the first pass of listArray to the `Chart` function, I've checked the items by displaying each of the names of the Process variable in the listArray and its still fine.

```
ProcessName    
p1
p2
p3
```

Also before passing of listArray to the `fcfsScheduling`, its still fine. (Output of the TEST CHECK fcfs)

```
p1
p2
p3
```

When it was passed in the `sjfNpScheduling`, the output was this:

```
null
p2
p3
```

UPDATE:
It was said that the problem was in the sjfNpscheduling function call is where the problem lies, but after debugging the code by just removing the fcfsScheduling call, the sjfNpScheduling worked.

```
p1
p2
p3
```

Was there any limitations of a List Collection being passed for more than two to an argument within a method?

Comment: And where is the code of `sjfNpScheduling`?

Comment: And where is the code of `Chart` function?

Comment: We can't really help you without you showing us all the relevant code. I can only guess that `sjfNpScheduling` removes the first element for some reason.

Comment: @Amongalen  I think it is not removing but setting it to null....

Comment: Debug your code for process at 0 index especially for if(isCompleted != true){
                    if(processBurst < leastBurstTime && processArrival <= timeFrame){}. Most probably following is not being executedtoProcess = currentProcess;
                        leastBurstTime = processBurst;
                        processIndex = i;

Comment: hmm... maybe you're right tho. I think its the code from the sjfNpScheduling but how come the listArray's first item got set to null too? isn't it that the default argument/parameter passing in java is passed by value?

Comment: @Amongalen there's no problem at all in my function. coz I've tried removing the instance of fcfsListArray, I've got the output that i wanted. But still there's still some questions left and its boggling me tho